Order Documents by the most items in an array contained in another array with pagination
I am currently using this whereField on my query for documents:
.whereField("tags", arrayContainsAny: ["Sports", "Fashion", "Gaming"]).
Where the "tags" field is an array of strings (ex: ["Sports", "Gaming"]. This works great to filter out any documents that have the tags field with none of the arrayContainsAny values in it. I am hoping to be able to sort the returned documents by number of tags inside of the arrayContainsAny array. For example if the tags field for a document had one value in the arrayContainsAny, it would have lower priority than one that had two values in the arrayContainsAny and so on. The logic would look something like this:
documents = documents.sorted { first, second in
    let firstNumberOfTagsInFilters = filters.filter { first.tags?.contains($0) ?? false }.count
    let secondNumberOfTagsInFilters = filters.filter { second.tags?.contains($0) ?? false }.count
    return firstNumberOfTagsInFilters > secondNumberOfTagsInFilters
}

The above code block works great to sort the returned documents. The only issue is I am using pagination with my query, so I wouldn't be able to sort the documents like this since I only retrieve a certain amount at a time:
query
    .whereField("tags", arrayContainsAny: tags)
    .limit(to: count)
    .startOptionally(afterDocument: lastDocument)

Is it possible to add this sort functionality in the query itself, before the limit? If not maybe an array isn't the best approach for these tags and different way is possible?

Does this answer your question? How to order documents by array field length in firebase firestore

Firestore can only order/filter on literal values that are present in the documents you query. There is no way to order/filter on calculated values, like you're trying to to.
For some use-cases (like the one Salvino linked: How to order documents by array field length in firebase firestore) you can store the calculated in the document itself and then filter on that, but for your use-case that'd only work if you can calculate the count for each filter combination you want to allow - which seems like it won't scale beyond a pretty small set of tags.
So if this use-case is crucial for your app, consider using another database that supports it.
